# Android wearable:2.0.5 Breaks Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, wear-os

I have a wearable drawer layout in my Android app. The behavior was that the peek view would display the peek fragment and when the user swiped up, the peek fragment would fade to the content fragment.

I recently attempted to update my android wear project from wearable 2.0.3 to wearable 2.0.5. A lot of components need to be changed from *wearable.view* to *wear.widget*.

After the update, both fragments display weather the drawer is open or closed. I tried fading these in and out manually, but there doesn't seem a way to do this smoothly or easily. Is the previous behavior possible anymore? I had to re-arrange things a bit as well to get it to work. Is there a different format I should be using that will get my previous behavior? Thanks!

Previous Drawer Layout:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom_action_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    app:drawer_content="@+id/nowPlayingFragment">
    <!-- Peek View -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/peekFragment"
        android:name="com.turndapage.navmusic.ui.fragment.PeekFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nowPlayingFragment"
        android:name="com.turndapage.navmusic.ui.fragment.NowPlayingFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.wearable.view.drawer.WearableActionDrawer>
```

New Drawer Layout:

```
<android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableActionDrawerView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_action_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    app:drawer_content="@+id/nowPlayingFragment"
    app:peekView="@+id/peek_view">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nowPlayingFragment"
        android:name="com.turndapage.navmusic.ui.fragment.NowPlayingFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Peek View -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/peekFragment"
        android:name="com.turndapage.navmusic.ui.fragment.PeekFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableActionDrawerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never found a solution I really liked, but here is one that works.

```
wearableDrawerLayout.setDrawerStateCallback(new WearableDrawerLayout.DrawerStateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(WearableDrawerLayout layout, int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(layout, newState);
            if(nowPlayingUtil != null) {
                // If the drawer is settling into position and it was opened all the way.
                if (wearableActionDrawer.getDrawerState() == WearableDrawerView.STATE_SETTLING && nowPlayingUtil != null) {
                    // Transitioning from peek view
                    if (drawerState == "drawerPeeking")
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToOpen();
                    // Transitioning from open view
                    else if (drawerState == "drawerOpen")
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToPeek();
                    else if (drawerState == "drawerClosed")
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToPeek();
                }
                if (wearableActionDrawer.getDrawerState() == WearableDrawerView.STATE_IDLE) {
                    // update the previous State
                    if (wearableActionDrawer.isOpened()) {
                        drawerState = "drawerOpen";
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToOpen();
                    } else if (wearableActionDrawer.isPeeking()) {
                        drawerState = "drawerPeeking";
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToPeek();
                    } else if (wearableActionDrawer.isClosed()) {
                        drawerState = "drawerClosed";
                        nowPlayingUtil.fadeToPeek();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So in my example, I have two functions, one for fadeToOpen and one for fadeToPeek which will animate the two views to make them visible or invisible. I can get about the same effect.

Still interested if there is a built in way to do this, but this will do for now.